# Can I add myself to group `root'?

Tags: permissions, sudo

```
$ id
uid=1000(kev) gid=1000(kev) groups=1000(kev),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)

$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 723 Jan 31  2012 /etc/sudoers

$ sudo adduser kev root
Adding user `kev' to group `root' ...
Adding user kev to group root
Done.

$ cat /etc/sudoers
cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

After adding myself(`kev`) to group `root`, I still cannot read `/etc/sudoers`.

I don't know why. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to log out and back in again for the change to take effect.

Comment: If you'd prefer refreshing groups w/o logging out, then check [harayz](http://askubuntu.com/a/498142/562148)'s answer.

Answer (score 15):

To refresh group membership of the user `kev` without logging out:

```
exec su -l kev
```

To make groupname your default group for the entire session:

```
newgrp groupname
```

To print current groups you're a member of ([source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-104-5/)):

```
groups
```